JSON event files to BQ
I have JSON files that are events (so there are millions of them) that are organized by date in my google storage, for example 2024-12-31/*.json. I have years worth of data.
I want combine this into a BQ table. So I did create table, point the source to gs://mydata and defined my schema elements and type JSON newline... so far so good.
Now if I do select * from myjsoncombinedtable where timestamp > "sometime", will BQ read all the millions of event files I have? If yes, that seems not very efficient. What would be a better way to do this?
